# Options screen for a simple dialer application - how do I?

Tags: android

I've written a very simple application that starts, in onCreate() dials a certain phone number then immediately finishes. I put a shortcut to this app on my home screen so I can dial that number by just clicking the shortcut.

Now I want to add an option to change the number. I could add a Setup menu to my app window but then I would have to add something like a Call Now menu or button as well. But I don't want to do that, I want my app to simply call a number and immediately quit. Is there any way I add the 'number to be called' setup screen elsewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some reading I can see I need to redesign my application to be a home screen widget. This way I will also have a possibility to setup & call as many numbers as I want.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution would be to create a ContentProvider to store/retrieve the desired phone number.  You could create a second app that used the ContentProvider to update the phone number.  Then you could use the ContentProvider in your current app to look up the phone number and call it.